# calabash-ios “Undefined Step” even though it exists

Tags: cucumber

Newbie to calabash-ios
Calabash-ios says "Undefined Step" even though it exists

I've wrote this code into **my_first.feature**

```
  Then I set “Name“ into “Yaseen“
```

After that I defined that step into  **my_first_steps.rb**

```
  Then(/^I set "([^\"]*)" into "([^\"]*)" $/) do |placeholder,input|
  set_text("textField placeholder:'#{placeholder}'",'#{input}')
  end
```

**It shows the step is undefined**

```
 You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Then(/^I set “Name“ into “Yaseen“$/) do
pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your step you have 'smart' quotes vs. straight quotes.

```
Then I set “Name“ into “Yaseen“
```

Change them to straight quotes.

```
Then I set "Name" into "Yaseen"
```

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any space before $/ in step definition. Try this

```
 Then(/^I set "([^\"]*)" into "([^\"]*)"$/) do |placeholder,input|
      set_text("textField placeholder:'#{placeholder}'",'#{input}')
      end
```

Comment: I copied the same code in my system, its working for me...Can you tell me the Folder structure of your project...